# How do I add a colleague's calender in Evolution from Exchange?

Tags: linux-mint, evolution, calendar, exchange

I know it works, because I have 10 calendars, all marked with ews, that somehow I added when I setup Evolution a gazillion years ago.

Now we got 2 new colleagues and I'm at total loss how to add them to my calendar.

See the 2 pictures:

[image]

[image]

These blacked out calendars are calendars from my colleagues I can view in Evolution. So somehow I added them. I just don't remember how. We have Windows Exchange Server, everybody but a few of us use Windows 10, so that's not a problem. There's a few of us that use Mac or Linux. Mac too is no problem, just Linux.

Answer (score 5):

- On the Mail view (NOT calendar), right click your exchange account, select "Subscribe to folder of other EWS user."
- Type in the name of the account you want, and choose "Calendar" from the dropdown.

This may fail if you can not access the details of the users calendar. You may be able to see their free/busy schedule by choosing "Free/Busy as calendar".

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with ews-hosted calendars, but I am managing an office with several CalDAV-hosted calendars, and the way I add them is by:

1. Opening the Evolution calendar window
2. Right-clicking the 'new' button
3. Clicking the 'Calendar' option
4. In the pop-up, changing the first field from 'local calendar' to 'CalDAV calendar'
5. Complete the rest of the form and hit 'enter'

In more recent versions of Gnome, you can also go to Settings and add a new calendar through 'Online Accounts'. The procedure should be similar, and it has the same result: all your calendars are added to evolution-data-server and are made available to gnome-aware calendar applications such as evolution.

HTH